# Как расчитать диаметр

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Всем привет, начал изучать opencv и подскажите как правильно высчитывать диаметр(2*r) окружности с полученных контуров. Но при выполнении кода он вообще странные значения выдает , я не понимаю как правильно высчитать диаметр, кто знает подскажите
Вот [ссылка](https://dropmefiles.com/h895S) на картинку которую использую.

**Вывод [90, 92, 126, 104, 92, 112]**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils


img = cv2.imread('coins.jpg')
output = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=100,
                           param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

detect_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
radii = []



for i, (x,y, r) in enumerate(detect_circles[0, :]):
    radii.append(r*2)
    cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0,255,0), 3, )
    cv2.putText(output, str(i + 1), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                (0, 255, 0), 2)

print(radii)
cv2.imshow('Image with Circles', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: почему эти значения странные и какие должны быть не странные?

Comment: Вы пробовали алгоритм Хафа для обнаружения эллипсоидов на изображении?

Comment: Почему у вас `maxRadius=0`?

Comment: @Эникейщик 
Если сравнивать физически диаметр, то она отличается
Например 2 рублевая монета диаметром  23,00 мм
а если через opencv то он выдает 104

Comment: @Ruin В пикселях значения примерно такие же как и найденные вручную на вашей картинке. Что вы подразумеваете под физическим диаметром (opencv не сможет дать вам размер в сантиметрах только в пикселях на изображении)

Comment: @gord1402 вот мне и надо, как то высчитать из пикселей, не могу найти формулу, если подскажите буду благодарен

Comment: @Ruin вам необходимо знать расстояние камеры от поверхности - `L` угловой размер пикселя - `a` (Угол обзора / разрешение по углу обзора) после по этой формуле находите `L*tan((a * d) / 2)` где d - диаметр в пикселях + для камеры прийдётся корректировать эффект рыбьего глаза

Comment: @gord1402, хорошо, спасибо Вам. Щас потестирую

Comment: @gord1402
Подскажете а нужно ли учитывать размер экрана на котором я тестирую? 
Потому что на разном расширении будет же разный размер пикселя, или мы это опускаем?

Comment: @Ruin количество пикселей на изображении зависит от камеры на которую снимали от экрана оно не зависит

Comment: пиксель всегда пиксель. Так же как и километр всегда километр независимо от размера и масштаба карты.

Comment: @gord1402, спасибо  Вам, Ваша формула помогла, есть погрешность, но это уже вторично